# Mysterious Hard Disk Failure?

Tags: disk, sata

My new 1,5 TB ext4 Hard Disk makes mysterious noises and fails to read and write. But not always. Sometimes it just works. But then I get those following errors. Does anyone know a solution for that or is my new WD Caviar Black 1.5 TB hard disk broken?

```
[  551.162286] ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[  551.162294] ata7.00: link offline, clearing class 1 to NONE
[  551.178223] ata7: EH complete
[  551.190802] ata7: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[  551.190807] ata7: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[  551.190811] ata7: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[  551.190818] ata7: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[  551.190822] ata7: hard resetting link
```

**Update** Mainboard P7P55D LE: http://www.asus.de/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1156/P7P55D_LE/#specifications

Comment: Can you add info about your motherboard?

Comment: I have the same error. I disconnected all sata devices and the error is still there. When the bios is starting I have an error briefly displayed about a JMicron NVRam disk that can't be mounted. The motherboard has 6 sata connectors. By disconnecting I mean completely removing the cords.

Comment: Do you have any other SATA controller? And do you have the _exact_ same errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy a new one, its broken. Now I hope everything works fine.
**Update** the second one worked for 6 days and now it is broken again. I will exchange it for a new model and hope for a little bit luck.

Comment: You need to limit to sata 1 with a jumper on the hdd.

Comment: This would be a solution to backup data?

Comment: No, it would be a solution to keep your hdd alive

Comment: Could it be that I never had this problem before until 6 days of usage (only just a few hours per day in those 6 days)?

Comment: I had problems with a sis sata chip on my motherboard. It was my secondary hdd, so I only used it for data. If I copied around 100 MB everything was ok, but at 1 GB and above it simply failed. I had to limit the bandwidth, and after it worked ok.

Comment: But it depends on the hard disk so the hard disk is broken? I want to use SATA 3 if I buy a SATA 3 hdd. I want to transfer much data.

Comment: some old motherboards which only support sata 1 are lack of some features which may result in such errors. But your case is different, as your motherboard is sata 3 capable.

Answer (score 4):

That SATA error is not good, but can only really be diagnosed by trying the following:

- pop this disk in another box
- put another disk in this box

That will narrow it down. If the disk still fails in the other box, try and get the data off it if it gives you some uptime, then ditch it

If the other disk fails in your computer, it is the SATA card, replace it (or if SATA is on the motherboard - you'll need to look at replacing the motherboard)

Comment: Now I have another failure with a new hard disk: [ 1043.423048] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[ 1043.423049] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1043.423051] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1043.423055] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0

Answer (score 2):

Cause: SATA II hard drives use autospeed negotiation. This enables our SATA II drives to automatically detect the motherboard data transfer rate, making it backward compatible with SATA I data transfer rates. However, some older SATA I controllers are unable to support autospeed negotiation and cannot recognize the drive. This “drive not detected” condition occurs when a chipset is incapable of correctly negotiating the data transfer speed with a SATA II hard drive.

To lock the drive at 150 MB/s data transfer rate install a jumper shunt on pins 5-6 (OPT1), shown in the picture below. (Only available on 3.5 inch (Desktop) size drives) 
[image]

From: http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/search/1/a_id/1337/c/130/p/227,279

Comment: Even the hard disk is SATA 3 and my mainboard supports SATA 3? (Mainboard P7P55D LE: [techspec](http://www.asus.de/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1156/P7P55D_LE/#specifications)) And hard disk is detected but results in errors (see the comment under rory alsop)

Comment: As your motherboard supports sata 3, your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone out - this immediately solved my problem.

If you are using a desktop computer, open it up and disconnect your DVD/CD drive. After doing this it booted up without incident. Just to make sure, I also booted into compatible mode from the GUI settings.

I wanted to clarify. I had read multiple forums over the net. With the 'compatibility mode' from the GUI setting and adding additional parameters, nothing appeared to be working after getting the ata7: hard resetting link. Now that I have finally loaded Linux Mint Cinnamon for the first time, I am installing it and will update this thereafter.

Comment: So, how'd it go?

Comment: this was big time guessing..could have been any of the sata drives...BUT, it was exactly the one that was causing my problems